# Not getting a full response from a rcon request to a server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I am using C# to query a Call of Duty 4 rcon to get status for the players, it works fine but it does not appear to receive a response of more than 1303 characters.

```
public string sendCommand(string rconCommand, string gameServerIP,
    string password, int gameServerPort)
{
    Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                               SocketType.Dgram,
                               ProtocolType.Udp);
    client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(gameServerIP), gameServerPort);

    string command;
    command = "rcon " + password + " " + rconCommand;
    byte[] bufferTemp = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
    byte[] bufferSend = new byte[bufferTemp.Length + 4];

    bufferSend[0] = byte.Parse("255");
    bufferSend[1] = byte.Parse("255");
    bufferSend[2] = byte.Parse("255");
    bufferSend[3] = byte.Parse("255");
    int j = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < bufferTemp.Length; i++)
    {
        bufferSend[j++] = bufferTemp[i];
    }

    IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint
        = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(gameServerIP), 0);
    client.Send(bufferSend, SocketFlags.None);
    byte[] bufferRec = new byte[64999];
    client.Receive(bufferRec);
    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferRec);
}
```

Apparently other people seem not have a problem with this but I am having problems with it. Does any one have any ideas?

Comment: What does `client.Receive` return?

Comment: client.Recive returns System.Byte[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My memory of the Quake RCON protocol is hazy, but I believe the special header is 5 bytes, `0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x02`. If that is not the case for COD4, then ignore this advice.

Additionally, you can't rely on the data being received all in one call to `Socket.Receive`. And my experience with Quake RCON is isn't always the best in returning, "as expected".

```
byte[] bufferSend = new byte[bufferTemp.Length + 5 ];
bufferSend[0] = 0xFF;
bufferSend[1] = 0xFF;
bufferSend[2] = 0xFF;
bufferSend[3] = 0xFF;
bufferSend[4] = 0x02;
Buffer.BlockCopy(bufferTemp, 0, bufferSend, 5, bufferTemp.Length);
...

StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
byte[] bufferRecv = new byte[65536];
do
{
    // loop on receiving the bytes
    int bytesReceived = client.Receive(bufferRecv);

    // only decode the bytes received
    response.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bufferRecv, 0, bytesReceived));
} while (client.Available > 0);

return response.ToString();
```

Comment: Worked good for a few times but when I attempted to do it on a 40 slot server it would only recive 1303 charecters again.

Comment: I've often found rcon to be unreliable, perhaps (and this is an ugly perhaps) you could try adding `Thread.Yield` after `response.Append` to see if it is a timing issue with `client.Available`.

Comment: Thread.Yield() didn't help, Gave me a headache converting a bit of code from 2.5 to 4. No idea whats not working, and I have no idea how to get it working.

Comment: AHA, got it. I think, I told the thread to sleep for 10 miliseconds and to remove ????print\n

Comment: That's more a fix for the symptom rather than the cause, basically you need to read until you think there isn't anymore, which is tough to tell! The server is allowed to send as many datagrams as they'd like. The network stack may break them up too. Basically your `Thread.Sleep` provides enough time for the other datagrams to arrive.